# When using glob for a certain folder, it does nothing but hang

Tags: python-3.x, glob

Firstly, let me apologize for the poorly worded title.

So, I am writing code to scan git repos, and my intention is to find all files, regardless of the name and extension. My problem is: when I try and scan (https://github.com/jcoglan/jsclass) < I am giving this as example, because this is the repo it hangs on, glob does nothing but hang, no errors, no timeout, nothing.. Let me show you my problem:

Clone the repo:

```
git -c /tmp/git clone https://github.com/jcoglan/jsclass
```

Run a simple glob search

```
import glob

repo = 'jcoglan/jsclass'
for file in glob.glob("/tmp/git/%s/**/*.txt" % repo, recursive=True):
    print(file)

print("here")
```

I have tried wrapping it in a `try` block, but that won't do anything because glob doesn't throw any errors, so my question is, what is causing `glob` to hang, and how can I fix it?

Comment: did you make sure you run the python script from the directory where you placed the `/tmp/git`, e.g. with `os.getcwd()`?

Comment: The script is run in a different directory than where the git repo is stored.

Comment: did you try to supply `glob.glob` with an absolute path then? For me, this runs perfectly fine; however I'm on Windows (needed to call the glob command as `glob.glob("tmp/git/%s/**/*.txt" % repo, recursive=True)` and repo is just `jsclass`) and can't test for Linux right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have symlinks on the path you are using glob on, then it could be due to a bug: https://bugs.python.org/issue43875

Comment: Link-only answers have risk of link going dead. Please consider providing summary/steps from link to solve the problem.